# Erased arguments in type constructors

Tags: idris, erasure, quantitative-types

What does it mean to erase an argument in a type constructor? For example

```
data Foo : (0 _ : Nat) -> Type where
```

as opposed to

```
data Foo : Nat -> Type where
```

My understanding is that nothing in a type constructor is used at runtime anyway, so it's effectively always 0. I guess it also leads to the perhaps more confusing question of what would a linear argument mean in a type constructor, but that's for another day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idris (2) is somewhat unusual in that it allows direct pattern matching on types. Type constructors are treated *as `Type`'s constructors*.

```
finSize : Type -> Maybe Nat
finSize (Fin n) = Just n
finSize _       = Nothing
```

If you, say, erased `Fin`'s argument, then matching against a `Type` with `Fin n` would make `n` erased, too.

```
data Fin : (0 _ : Nat) -> Type where

-- fails
-- finSize : Type -> Maybe Nat
-- finSize (Fin n) = Just n  -- have 0 copies of n, need at least 1
-- finSize _       = Nothing
-- succeeds
data Erased : Type -> Type where Erase : (0 _ : a) -> Erased a
finSize : Type -> Maybe (Erased Nat)
finSize (Fin n) = Just (Erase n)
finSize _       = Nothing
```

Comment: interesting. I wonder whether that means that one should typically erase arguments to type constructors or not

Comment: @joel I would err on "no". *Types* themselves should be erased when possible. (E.g. when a type is implicitly quantified from a lowercase identifier, it is implicitly given a `0` quantity.) Making the arguments to types erased will just make your life harder on the off chance you ever do unerase a type.